# Get the first word and char on the name of png file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv, png

l have a set of png images which are named as follow

```
slash_67_45.png
A_91_14.png
a_38_10.png
%_34_45.png
é_67_78.png
è_67_56.png
e_67_10.png
B_56_54.png
b_45_45.png
@_34_45.png
À_34_5.png
à_23_6.png
7_23_6.png
'_254.png
"_23.png
\_67.png
[_45.png
```

l want to retrieve only the words or character before the first `'_'` and store that in a column in csv file as follow

```
charachter_column         its-image               imag-without-character


    slash                 slash_67_45.png         _67_45.png
    A                     A_91_14.png             _91_14.png
    a                     a_38_10.png             _38_10.png
    %                     %_34_45.png             _34_45.png
    é                     è_67_78.png             _67_78.png
    è                     é_67_56.png             _67_56.png
    e                     e_67_10.png             _67_10.png
    B                    B_56_54.png              _56_54.png
    b                     b_45_45.png             _45_45.png
    @                     @_34_45.png             _34_45.png
    À                      A_34_5.png             _34_5.png
    à                      à_23_6.png             _23_6.png
    7                      7_23_6.png             _23_6.png
    '                       '_254.png             _254.png
    "                        "_23.png             _23.png
    \                        \_67.png             _67.png
    [                        [_45.png             _45.png
```

Here is the code l tried :

```
import os
import pandas as pd
charachter_column= []
its_image=[]
image_without_character=[]

temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'charachter_column ': charachter_column , 'its_image ': its-image,
'image_without_character' : image_without_character})
temp_df.to_csv('/home/images_charac.csv')

DATA_DIR = "/home/images/"
png_files=sorted(os.listdir(DATA_DIR))
for png in png_files:
    print(os.path.join(DATA_DIR,file))
    file_name=file
    character_column= file_name[:file_name.find("_")]
    image_without_character=file_name[file_name.find("_")+1:]

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'charachter_column ': charachter_column , 'its_image ': file_name,
'image_without_character' : image_without_character})
temp_df.to_csv('/home/images_charac.csv')
```

the problem here it's that l have 3 `'_'` l want to consider only the first `'_'` encountered from the left

Comment: @Ivan Kolenikov thank you for editing

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you’ve written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: @Crispin , sorry l forgot to share what l(ve tried pease see the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be some other issues with your code, but this example should address the root issue you're facing:

```
files = ['slash_67_45.png',
'A_91_14.png',
'a_38_10.png',
'%_34_45.png',
'é_67_78.png',
'è_67_56.png',
'e_67_10.png',
'B_56_54.png',
'b_45_45.png']

for png_file in files:
    character, everything_else = png_file.split('_',maxsplit=1)
    print(character)
```

out

```
A --- 91_14.png
a --- 38_10.png
% --- 34_45.png
é --- 67_78.png
è --- 67_56.png
e --- 67_10.png
B --- 56_54.png
b --- 45_45.png
```

EDIT

It looks like you want to keep the '_'. In that case, you could do this:

```
for png_file in files:
    character, sep, everything_else = png_file.partition('_')
    print(character,'---', sep + everything_else)
```

out

```
slash --- _67_45.png
A --- _91_14.png
a --- _38_10.png
% --- _34_45.png
é --- _67_78.png
è --- _67_56.png
e --- _67_10.png
B --- _56_54.png
b --- _45_45.png
```

Comment: Thank you Crispin